# Random variables are equal almost surely

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables

I am trying to prove that if $X_n \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow \infty]{L^2} Y$ and $X_n \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow \infty]{\text{a.s.}} Z$ then we get $\mathbb{P}(Y=Z)=1$.

I have so far that $X_n \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow \infty]{L^1} Y \Rightarrow X_n \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow \infty]{P} Y $ (because we have convergence in $L^2$). Then we have that there exists a subsequence such that $X_{n_k} \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow \infty]{\text{a.s.}} Y$. Furthermore $X_n \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow \infty]{\text{a.s.}} Z \Rightarrow X_n \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow \infty]{P} Z$ then there exists a subsequence such that $X_{n_k} \xrightarrow[n \rightarrow \infty]{\text{a.s.}} Z$.

Is that enough to conclude that $Y=Z$ almost surely? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, since $X_n\to Y$ in $L^1$, $X_{n_k}\to Y$ a.s. along some subsequence $n_k$. Also $X_{n_k}\to Z$ a.s. along the same subsequence trivially. Thus, $Y=Z$ a.s.

Comment: With hindsight it's obvious that I don't need $X_n$ to converge in probability to $Z$ (Bolzano-Weierstrass). Thanks!